# Equivalent to c# EventHandler in Dash?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been developing an app in c# for some time now, and am interested in using the Flutter SDK to possibly switch to in the future. I've come to love using EventHandlers and delegates in c# to create and trigger custom events and am trying to find an equivalent in Dart. Is something like this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post at least some code that you want to have translated and what the expected behavior is. Not everyone working with Dart also knows C# well. For events one usually uses streams, types for delegates can be defined as `typedef` or inline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  var myClass = new MyClass();
  var subscription = myClass.onMyEvent.listen((e) => print('new event: $e'));
  myClass.emit(true);
  myClass.emit(false);
  subscription.cancel();
  myClass.emit(null);

  new MyDelegateExample()
    ..addHandler((val) => print('1: $val'))
    ..dispatch('a');

  new MyDelegateExample2()
    ..addHandler((val) => print('2: $val'))
    ..dispatch('b');
}
```

**custom events**

```
class MyClass {
  final _onMyEvent = new StreamController<bool>.broadcast(sync: true);

  Stream<bool> get onMyEvent => _onMyEvent.stream;

  void emit(bool val) => _onMyEvent.add(val);
}
```

**delegates with inlined type**

```
class MyDelegateExample {
  var _handlers = <void Function(String e)>[];

  void addHandler(void Function(String e) handler) => _handlers.add(handler);

  void dispatch(String x) => _handlers.forEach((h) => h(x));
}
```

**delegates with `typedef`**

```
typedef void Handler(String e);

class MyDelegateExample2 {
  var _handlers = <Handler>[];

  void addHandler(Handler handler) => _handlers.add(handler);

  void dispatch(String x) => _handlers.forEach((h) => h(x));
}
```